# install and setup 2.4 or 2.3 Bigbluebutton without Docker

Tags: java, docker, bigbluebutton, docker-pull

i have tried to install BigBlueButton many times and i failed each time, most of my problems comes from mongodb,docker and anything that blocked access from ip of my country ( iran )
i have found solution for mongodb and others but still cant find a solution for docker problem .
i have taken a look at bbb-install.sh and only time that docker is used outside of install_greenlight() function is this

```
297    install_docker                            # needed for bbb-libreoffice-docker
298    docker pull openjdk:11-jre-buster      # fix issue 413
299    docker tag openjdk:11-jre-buster openjdk:11-jre
```

is there anyway for me to not to use docker for openjdk ? and if yes how ? ( i do not know anything about docker )

many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

did not find a way to completely stop using docker but found a mirror for docker
and here is how to use it :

```
cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json <<EOF
{
  "registry-mirrors": ["https://mirror.example"]
}
EOF
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mirrors or VPN(Not recommended)
or you can change dns using resolvconf
by this commands

```
sudo apt install resolvconf

sudo systemctl status resolvconf.service


 sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

then set your name servers
after that:

```
sudo resolvconf --enable-updates

sudo resolvconf -u
```

ensure you set dns correctly:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

now you can install mongodb or bbb or greenlight

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Best way to install bigbluebutton on servers that colocated in Iran or any sanctioned countries is using [shecan](https://shecan.ir)
First set shecan as your DNS nameserver inside /etc/resolve.conf or in network configuration file, then start installing Bigbluebutton, if you want have more speed on each installation it's better to make local mirror for bigbluebutton repositories. After finishing installation it's better to set cloudflare or Google DNS on your server.